# blazor.net with HttpClient sending credentials

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, blazor

I have an api hosted on IIS that I am trying to call through a Blazor.Net client app with the `HttpClient` as provided in the example.

Since the api endpoint is hosted on IIS with windows authentication, I need to include credentials when the call is made.

I tried to create an instance of the `httpClient` instead of using the static method provided in the examples but I receive the **`PlatformNotSupported`** **exception**.

Is there a way to pass credentials with the Static `HttpClient` as used in `Blazor.net`?

If I use JavaScript interop with `XMLHttpRequest` and set `withCredentials` to `true`, the api returns data.  However I would rather not use js to get the data but rather C#.

Thanks,

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I have not worked with Blazor since its 1.x release.  I ended using Javascript Web Tokens instead.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the browser should take care of this, that's why you need a browser that is Windows Authentication compatible. See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mist/2018/02/14/windows-authentication-http-request-flow-in-iis/) for an explanation of how Windows Authentication interacts with the browser.

So if that does not work by default, I guess Blazor/Mono does not supports this yet. But you are able to include your own authorization headers in the http call in blazor. I have an example [here](https://github.com/floreseken/BlazorExtensions/blob/master/BlazorExtensions/Http.cs) how to do that (for a jwt token). So if you are able to somehow get the Windows token from somewhere you could try that.

Comment: Thanks I didn't consider extension methods and did not know about the Handler.  I will try them.